# Solve PDE with Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to know if it is possible to solve 1D heat conduction equation with Tensorflow. The equation is:

[image]

Is it possible to convert the following python code into Tensorflow input? Thank you very much.

```
# Initial and boundary conditions 
T = np.ones(shape=(mesh_num+1,1))*T_amb
T[0] = 0.
T[mesh_num] = 0.

# Solve discrete equation 
for k in range(Total_itr_num):
    epsT = np.sin(3.0*np.pi/200.0*T)
    source = epsT *(T_amb**4-T**4) + h*(T_amb-T)

    for ii in range(mesh_num-1):
        i = ii + 1
        T[i] = 0.5*(T[i+1]+T[i-1]+source[i]*dx*dx)
```